# Templates for video online

Tags: open-source, video, networking

I'm not so good with video editing, so sometimes I used templates for creating video (it's always fast and simple).  Before I used those templates: https://videoeditor.com/templates.html.
Maybe you know services like this, but with more templates (or maybe services for creating templates).

It should be free (I'm not ready to buy this), not desktop (I used this not so often)
 and of course simple.

Thanks a lot